# Which chemical should be added on recycling LDPE to make the granules brighter

Tags: recycling

What should be added while recycling LDPE(low density polyethylene ) to brighten the granules. Which chemical should be used and how much amount.

Comment: That is a chemistry (and maybe engineering) question. Please delete it here and check if is on-topic for http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I question why a cosmetic effect on the raw input stream has relevance to sustainability.